# How to access variables defined and declared in one function in another function?

Tags: c++, scope

Can anyone tell me how to access variables declared and defined in one function in another function.

E.g

```
void function1()
{
   string abc;
}

void function2()
{
   // I want to access abc here.
}
```

How can I achieve that besides using parameters?

Comment: I suggest you read up on scoping, and you will understand why it's not possible.

Comment: This simply makes no sense: there is one instance of `abc` per invocation of  `function1`. In `for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { function1(); }` which of the one hundred instances of `abc` do you want?

Comment: Do you know about static members ?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Why are you seeking to do this? As you can see from the answers, there are a number of alternatives available. What you should do is dependent on the specific goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well I am ignoring parameter method because I am using Qt and there are problems when I use void function1(QString& abc) and it gives me some weird error but if I use void function1(int& abcd) it compiles correctly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The C++ way is to pass `abc` by reference to your function:

```
void function1()
{
    std::string abc;
    function2(abc);
}
void function2(std::string &passed)
{
    passed = "new string";
}
```

You may also pass your string as a pointer and dereference it in function2. This is more the C-style way of doing things and is not as safe (e.g. a NULL pointer could be passed in, and without good error checking it will cause undefined behavior or crashes.

```
void function1()
{
    std::string abc;
    function2(&abc);
}
void function2(std::string *passed)
{
    *passed = "new string";
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Make it global then both can manipulate it.

```
string abc;

void function1(){
    abc = "blah";
} 

void function2(){
    abc = "hello";
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but the OP specifically states, `variables declared and defined in a function`.

Comment: If he is not familiar with variable scope, then it is possible he did not know this way was possible.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a variable in function1 that you want to use in function2, then you must either:

1. pass it directly,
2. have a higher scope function that calls both
   declare the variable and pass it, or
3. declare it a global and then all functions can access it

If your function2 is called from function1, then you can just pass it as an argument to function2.

```
void function1()  
{  
    std::string abc;  
    function2( abc );  
}  

void function2( std::string &passed )   
{   
    // function1::abc is now aliased as passed and available for general usage.
   cout << passed << " is from function1.";   
}
```

If function1 doesn't call function2, but both are called by function3, then have function3 declare the variable and pass it to both function1 and function2 as an argument.

```
void parentFunction( )
{
    std::string abc;  
    function1( abc );  
    function2( abc );  
}
void function1( std::string &passed )   
{   
   // Parent function's variable abc is now aliased as passed and available for general usage.
   cout << passed << " is from parent function.";   
}   
void function2( std::string &passed )   
{   
    // Parent function's variable abc is now aliased as passed and available for general usage.
   cout << passed << " is from parent function.";   
}
```

Finally, if neither function1 nor function2 is called from each other, nor from the same function in code, then declare the variable to be shared as a global, and function1 and function2 will be able to directly use it.

```
std::string global_abc;  
void function1( )   
{   
   cout << global_abc << " is available everywhere.";   
}   
void function2( )   
{   
   cout << global_abc << " is available everywhere.";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way. Variables of the block can be directly accessed ONLY from that block.

Pointers/references to the object can be passed into functions that are called from this block as parameters.

Comment: This is, of course, false. Scoping limits the name of an object from being visible in another block. It does not limit access to the object. Access can be obtained by passing references, among other means.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but references to what? Scoping defines the lifetime of the object too, unless it is static or dynamically allocated. Furthermore OP specified "no parameters".

Comment: Put the reference in a global variable. Pass the reference to the other function. Pass the reference to a function that makes it accessible to the other function. Take a pointer as a parameter, and store the reference in the pointed-to location. Etc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP wants to know how to "how to access variables declared and defined in a function..."

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, so? As I wrote, access can be obtained by a variety of means. Another one is to use the introspection facilities provided by debugging information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil none of those methods work with OP's (rather bizarre) constraints.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Which constraints do they violate? The question specifies three constraints: Declared and defined in one function. Accessed in another. Not using parameters. The global variable method satisfies all of those constraints. Passing the reference to a function (i.e., through a subroutine called from the function, not through the function’s parameters) satisfies those constraints. Using the debugging facilities satisfies those constraints.