# access variables from other function c++

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables, local

I must access variables declared inside other function.

Assume `f1()`

```
void f1()
{
  double a;
  int b;
  //some operations
}
```

and `f2()`

```
void f2()
{
  //some operations
  //access a and b from f1()
}
```

Is it possilbe in c++? How can that be done?

Passing reference to function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783435/how-to-access-variables-defined-and-declared-in-one-function-in-another-function.) is not suitable answer for my case because this corrupts the order of calling functions. Declaring global variables also denied.

Comment: Your aim clearly violates the *"Code against the interface, not its implementation."* rule.

Comment: What are you allowed to change in this bizarre homework assignment?

Comment: Make them global if you have to

Comment: Doing exactly what you say is impossible. Perhaps you can give us more information about what you want to achieve, then we can suggest the right way to do it.

Comment: You may do whatever you want except two conditions described above

Comment: "this corrupts the order of calling functions" - also causes beer to come out of monkey's nose?

Comment: No, it's not possible, because like most languages, C++ is lexically scoped. Closures might allow you get kind-of get around this (stupid/bizarre) requirement, but who knows what the person that asked this is thinking.

Answer (score 7):

In C++ there is no way to access locally declared function variables outside of that function's scope. Simply put, what you are asking for here:

> I must access variables declared inside another function.

is simply impossible. Anything you try that *seems* to allow you to do that is undefined behavior.

What you can do is turn "f1" and "f2" as methods of a class and put `double a` and `int b` as member data states:

```
class c1
{
  double a;
  int b;

public:
  void f1();
  void f2();
};

void c1::f1()
{
  // f1 can access a and b.
  //some operations
}

void c1::f2()
{
  // f2 can see the changes made to a and b by f1
}
```

This fulfills your two requirements. Namely:

1. No global variables are used.
2. No parameter references are passed into the methods in question.

Comment: Thanks, but you declared double a and int b as global?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov `a` and `b` are not global, they are class data members specific to a given instance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to call `f2` from some other place than `f1`, e.g.

```
void foo() { f1(); f2(); }
```

If that's the case: those variables don't even exist at the time `f2` is called, so there's nothing to access.
(And you're mistaking *scope* for *lifetime*. Those are very different things.)

One thing you *can* do is pass the variables by reference to all the functions that need them.

```
void f1(double& a, int& b);
void f2(double& a, int& b);

void foo()
{
    double x;
    int y;
    f1(x, y);
    f2(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something similar as what greatwolf suggested. You can use a class declaration inside your function. This serves the following purpose:
You can define a function that is only available in the current scope, so not accessible outside of that scope and that function has access to variables within that scope as if they were global. The class is also only defined in your current scope.

```
void    MyVeryComplicatedFunction
{
    int A;
    class localvars
    {
    public:
        int *ARef;              // this serves as the "Global" variables
        std::vector<int>    B;  // this serves as the "Global" variables

        localvars(int *inA) ARef(inA);

        void RepetativeOperation(int C) {
            (*ARef) += C;
            B.push_back(C);
        }
    }localvars(A);

    localvars.B.push_back(4);
    A = 3;
    localvars.RepetativeOperation(2);
    localvars.RepetativeOperation(4);
    localvars.RepetativeOperation(8);

    printf("A = %d, B[3] = %d", A, localvars.B[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class c1 {
    string a;
    string b;

public:
    void f1();
    void f2();
};

void c1::f1() {
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    f2();
}

void c1::f2() {
    cout << "vals are: " << a << b;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of your solution?