# Can I access a variable in a function which is in a class through an object?

Tags: c++

```
class A 
{ 
int a;
double b;
public:
A(){a=20;B=78.438;}
void data()
{ int num1; num1=a;}
}
```

I have above CPP code.
Can I access 'num1' variable using object of class A type?

I think this question is different than "[How to access variables defined and declared in one function in another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783435/how-to-access-variables-defined-and-declared-in-one-function-in-another-function)".

Because here I want to access variable , which is in the function, which is a member of the class A. And I want access through object of class A type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access variables defined and declared in one function in another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783435/how-to-access-variables-defined-and-declared-in-one-function-in-another-function)

Comment: This question is different because here I am accessing variable, which is in the function which is a member of the class A. And I want access through object of class A type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I access 'num1' variable using object of class A type?

No, you cannot.`num1` is declared inside a function `data()` so you have no access to it through object of type A. You would have to move declaration of `int num1;` to class body.:

```
class A 
{ 
  int a;
  double b;
  public:
  int num1;
  A(){a=20;B=78.438;}
  void data()
  {  
    num1=a;
  }
}
```

now you can write:

```
A a;
a.num1 = 1;
```