# Call the function as argument in another function in R

Tags: r, function, api, arguments, plumber

I am Developing an API for that I am using Plumber. I have created two function with its each endpoint.
I want to use function 1 as argument in function 2 **OR** inheritance for example function  1 should be my parent class and function 2 will be my child class.

I want to reuse the code of function 1 for executing function 2 output.

**I don't know how to do!**

Please Help

Thank You in Advance

**Function 1**

```
library(plumber)
library(gwasrapidd)

#* @get /Query    

simplequery <- function(query=""){

    studies <- get_studies(study_id = query) 

  }
```

**Function 2**

```
#* @get /GetData
    
    Getdata <- function(of=""){
          
          if (of == "Studies"){
            
            study_table <- studies@studies
            
            .....
          }
        }
```

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. It is very unclear to me from the code you wrote what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to make function 1 to be my parent class and function 2 to be child class

Comment: function 1 and function 2 should be connected

Comment: Still do not understand.. Do you have an example in another language?

Comment: @BrunoTremblay  function 1 will get the query from user and whatever result will come from function 1 that result is going to store into variable(Studies, Association, Variants, Traits). So, thing is that I want pass that function 1 variable to the function 2 for another statement of code.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay  you can checkout this question                              
                                                            
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783435/how-to-access-variables-defined-and-declared-in-one-function-in-another-function**  but it is in C++

Comment: Read the answers there, it is the same for R.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay I still not get this How to do. Can you please help me out

Comment: I have done as much as I can, the rest is up to you. Sorry.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay Thank Sir for your Response. I used with function to solve with my query

Answer (score 0):

I have used `with` function to inherit my function.

```
abc <- function{
    with(parent.frame(),{
       function_statement
    })
}

efg<- function{
    d <- abc()
    function_statement
}
```

what it does is that efg function calls the abc function